# Why is this Powershell service wrapper running old code?

Tags: powershell, service

I'm using the service wrapper example at this link: http://jf.larvoire.free.fr/progs/PSService.ps1

Additionally, I've commented out the region SampleCode, and have this instead:

```
if ($Service) {                 # Run the service
  Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1005 -EntryType Information -Message "$scriptName -Service # Beginning background job"
  # Do the service background job
  try {
    # Start the control pipe handler thread
    $pipeThread = Start-PipeHandlerThread $pipeName -Event "ControlMessage"
    ######### TO DO: Implement your own service code here. ##########
    <# commented SampleCode #>
    ##Setup watcher here
    . .\FileSystemEventProcessor.ps1
    $global:FSWatcher = [FSWatcher]::new()
    #TODO: Load saved auto-watch list
    #TODO: Load modules  from saved list
    $ModulesToLoad = 'PublishFSEventsToCSV'#,'WriteToConsole'
        #Import-Module (Resolve-Path("$installDir\Modules\PublishFSEventsToCSV"))
    <#
    foreach($mod in $ModulesToLoad) {
        $modPath = "$installDir\Modules\$mod.psm1"
        Log (Resolve-Path($modPath))
        Import-Module (Resolve-Path($modPath))
        if(((Get-Command -Module $mod -ListImported) | Where-Object Name -eq 'begin').Length -ne 1) {throw 'FSWatcher Modules must have a begin function to call.'}
        (& (Get-Command -Module $mod -Name begin) 1)
    }
    #>               

    do { # Keep running until told to exit by the -Stop handler
      $event = Wait-Event # Wait for the next incoming event
      $source = $event.SourceIdentifier
      $message = $event.MessageData
      $eventTime = $event.TimeGenerated.TimeofDay
      Write-Debug "Event at $eventTime from ${source}: $message"
      Log "Debug: message type is $($message.GetType())."
      $event | Remove-Event # Flush the event from the queue
      switch ($message) {
        "ControlMessage" { # Required. Message received by the control pipe thread
          $state = $event.SourceEventArgs.InvocationStateInfo.state
          Write-Debug "$script -Service # Thread $source state changed to $state"
          switch ($state) {
            "Completed" {
              $message = Receive-PipeHandlerThread $pipeThread
              Log "$scriptName -Service # Received control message: $Message"
              if ($message -ne "exit") { # Start another thread waiting for control messages
                $pipeThread = Start-PipeHandlerThread $pipeName -Event "ControlMessage"
              }
            }
            "Failed" {
              $error = Receive-PipeHandlerThread $pipeThread
              Log "$scriptName -Service # $source thread failed: $error"
              Start-Sleep 1 # Avoid getting too many errors
              $pipeThread = Start-PipeHandlerThread $pipeName -Event "ControlMessage" # Retry
            }
          }
        }
        default { # Should not happen
          Log "$scriptName -Service # Unexpected event from ${source}: $Message"
        }
      }
    } while ($message -ne "exit")

  } catch { # An exception occurred while runnning the service
    $msg = $_.Exception.Message
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    Log "$scriptName -Service # Error at line ${line}: $msg"
  } finally { # Invoked in all cases: Exception or normally by -Stop

    foreach($mod in $ModulesToLoad) {
        if(((Get-Command -Module $mod -ListImported) | Where-Object Name -eq 'end').Length -ne 1) {(& (Get-Command -Module $mod -Name end) 1)}
        if ((Get-Module -Name $mod) -ne $null) {Remove-Module -Name $mod}
    }
    $global:FSWatcher.Dispose()

    # Terminate the control pipe handler thread
    Get-PSThread | Remove-PSThread # Remove all remaining threads
    # Flush all leftover events (There may be some that arrived after we exited the while event loop, but before we unregistered the events)
    $events = Get-Event | Remove-Event
    # Log a termination event, no matter what the cause is.
    Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $serviceName -EventId 1006 -EntryType Information -Message "$script -Service # Exiting"
    Log "$scriptName -Service # Exiting"
  }
  return
}
```

Now, I've used the -remove and -setup options several times, but at some point, the compiled script refuses to run the contents of the script, and is instead running an older copy of the script. The error I get (into C:\Windows\Logs\FileSystemWatcherService.log is this:

```
2023-09-21 09:08:06 1384 DDD\UName .\FileSystemWatcherService.ps1 -Setup -verbose
2023-09-21 09:08:07 1384 DDD\UName FileSystemWatcherService.ps1 -Setup # Configuring the service to run by default as LocalSystem
2023-09-21 09:08:22 5348 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM & 'D:\FileSystemWatcher\FileSystemWatcherService.ps1' -SCMStart
2023-09-21 09:08:22 5348 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM FileSystemWatcherService.ps1 -SCMStart: Starting script 'D:\FileSystemWatcher\FileSystemWatcherService.ps1' -Service
2023-09-21 09:08:22 1028 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM & 'D:\FileSystemWatcher\FileSystemWatcherService.ps1' -Service
2023-09-21 09:08:23 1028 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM FileSystemWatcherService.ps1 -Service # Error at line 183: The specified module '.\Modules\PublishFSEventsToCSV.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

The line it's complaining about is the line that's been changed, and is currently commented out in the code above, and thus in the code it's supposedly referencing. I've checked post -Setup run, and the script at the install directory is indeed the current script, but when I start the installed service, this error happens consistently.

I feel like there's a layer of caching somewhere that I'm not properly clearing, but I don't know where to find it.

Any help would be appreciated.